# system thinks it is maxed out on storage

Tags: ssh, storage

I seem to have run into a strange issue that is causing many problems.
for context, I am sshing into a 22.04.01 server VM constructed on a truNAS network with 18.1G storage and 12G RAM. I am using this to run game servers for me and my friends to play on using docker compose.   I ssh into my VM I'm told

```
Usage of /:                       97.4% of 18.10GB
```

and this is causing many programs to crash due to insufficient space to write to. The strange part of this is that when I run `sudo du -h -c` I'm told that I have  `7.0G    total`
`df` tells me

```
Filesystem                        1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                               1225632     1208   1224424   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  18979548 18481136         0 100% /
tmpfs                               6128144        0   6128144   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                  5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                            996780   253176    674792  28% /boot
/dev/sda1                            523248     5364    517884   2% /boot/efi
overlay                            18979548 18481136         0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/66d9968b0ff8831f98a9f1d3839beb5d233a7996d1ebe30513f0078c1f939bdd/merged
tmpfs                               1225628        4   1225624   1% /run/user/1000
overlay                            18979548 18481136         0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c4171ec1c8aa69a129f0a327bb70f84deb6e15ab2608b61e1934afe80ca96a6d/merged
```

`801M` is being used in `/var/log/journal/944d63898a804cb69cf9b59f62532cb0` but I cant read the files in there.
output for `sudo du -hcxs /` is just

```
18G     /
18G     total
```

Please do ask for more information as needed as im not sure what to provide!

Comment: What does `df` tell you, also can you install and run `tune2fs -l /dev/whatever` to see reserved blocks

Comment: Do any of the programs that are writing to disk use sparse files? That could account for the discrepancy. Note that about 2GB of your storage is going to be dedicated to the `root` account to ensure logs can be written when the main user space has run out of storage.

Comment: @matigo what are sparse files? I'm pretty new to all of this stuff and just started high school this year so I have not been able to focus on it as much

Comment: @thomasrutter I'm not seeing ```tune2fs``` in apt, how do I install that?

Comment: That `100%` for `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` is certainly an issue. Check your log directory (`/var/log`) for large files as that's often the first place to check. Be sure to *read* some of the logs before deleting them so that you can find out what problem is being reported (aside from a lack of space) as log files should not consume more than a few hundred MB in normal circumstances.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo du -hcxs /`?  Also, if you can, try to install `ncdu` and run `ncdu -x /` to show where all your space is being used.

Comment: @Terrance i can not install that due to the root of the issue

Comment: @Thewolfhearted tune2fs is in e2fsprogs.  

Looks like your root is full though.  I don't know why du only showed 7GB

Comment: @Thewolfhearted You may have only ran the `du` command originally within another directory which will return the amount of space used in just that directory and none other, unless specified after the switches which you didn't show us if you did. `df` on the other hand will return available and used for all mounts. I had you run that `du` command in my other comment to show that the entire mount is full.  Have you removed downloaded files?  Maybe check the `/var/logs` directory for big log files as you may be experiencing an issue with your OS?

Comment: Also, 18GB can fill up really fast in an environment like that. I have VMs that are clean installs that are already at 13GB. I also have a Xubuntu 22.04 VM I just spun up at 18GB.  Consider a larger mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I ran `sudo du -h -c` in the wrong directory and I am actually out of storage, simple mistake on my part!